# Elastic Search Bulk Update using python, how to append a array field with new data

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

how to update field in elastic search using bulkupdate in python. i tried many ways its all getting error. In some cases i am getting document missing error , how do i update and upsert at same time . and also appending to field is not working.elasticsearch==7.9.1  is the package i used in python

```
for i in range(0, length, steps):
    end_index = length-1 if i+steps>length else i+steps
    temp_list = test_data[i: end_index]
    bulk_file = ''
    actions = [{
        "_index": "test-data",
        "_opt_type":"update",
        "_type": "test-test-data",
        "_id": test_row ['testId'],
        "doc":{"script": {
                          "source": "ctx._source.DataIds.add(params.DataIds)",
                          "lang": "painless",
                          "params": {
                              "DataIds":test_row ['DataIds']
                          }
                      }}
        }
        for test_row in temp_list
    ]
    helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

Error iam getting is this

```
    {'update': {'_index': 'test-data', '_type': 'products', '_id': '333', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'failed
 to execute script', 'caused_by': {'type': 'script_exception', 'reason': 'runtime error', 'script_stack': ['ctx._source.dataIds.add(params.dataIds)', '
    ^---- HERE'], 'script': 'if (ctx._source.dataIds == null) { ctx._source.dataIds = []; } ctx._source.dataIds.add(params.dataIds)', 'lang': 'painless', 'position': {'offse
t': 105, 'start': 71, 'end': 118}, 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'dynamic method [java.lang.String, add/1] not found'}}}, 'data': {'upsert': {}, 'scripted_up
sert': True, 'script': {'source': 'if (ctx._source.dataIds == null) { ctx._source.dataIds = []; } ctx._source.dataIds.add(params.dataIds)', 'lang': 'painless', 'params': {'c
dataIds': 'set123'}}}}}])
```

Comment: @Lupanoide when i change to  doc field, fields in the elastic search are added like this "doc.script.lang
painless". iam not able to update DataIds field

Comment: @Lupanoide Bulk updation is not possible with script. i don't whats wrong with the code. all fields inside "doc" is added as field in elastic search eg : "doc.script.lang :"painless"

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue but "_opt_type" should be "_op_type"

Comment: @ekmcd its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to [`upsert` via script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) is without the `doc` but only the `script` section. You also need the `upsert` section if you want to upsert and update in the same command. It goes like this:

```
actions = [{
    "_op_type":"update",
    "_index": "test-data",
    "_type": "test-test-data",
    "_id": test_row ['testId'],
    "upsert": {
       "DataIds": test_row ['DataIds']
    },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.DataIds.add(params.DataIds)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
           "DataIds":test_row ['DataIds']
        }
    }
} for test_row in temp_list
]
```

Another way to do it is with [`scripted_upsert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#scripted_upsert)

```
actions = [{
    "_op_type":"update",
    "_index": "test-data",
    "_type": "test-test-data",
    "_id": test_row ['testId'],
    "upsert": {},
    "scripted_upsert": true,
    "script": {
        "source": "if (ctx._source.DataIds == null) { ctx._source.DataIds = []; } ctx._source.DataIds.add(params.DataIds)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
           "DataIds":test_row ['DataIds']
        }
    }
} for test_row in temp_list
]
```

Comment: i am getting this error 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason'
: 'failed to execute script', 'caused_by': {'type': 'script_exception', 'reason': 'runtime error',@Val

Comment: It's already better :-) Can you update your question with the full error you're getting?

Comment: The error means that in some document `dataIds` is a string and not an array. Is that possible? `dynamic method [java.lang.String, add/1] not found`

Comment: yes it was because dataIds where string,it is fixed and  when i tried with  scripted_upsert way . Null values are getting appended in dataIds. may be because painless script

Comment: Can you show how the bulk command looks like when you append null values ?

Comment: i was stuck about 3 days , it is a great relief now

Comment: No, because ES would have no way to know which document to update

Comment: i know another field in the document which unique , can we use that field for updation, is there is any way for query and update

Comment: I think you should create another question because this one is solved now and that's another issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223281/discussion-between-nithish-albin-and-val).